# Get corresponding y-axis value for x-axis in HighCharts

Tags: highcharts

How would I get corresponding y-axis value for any x-axis value in HighCharts? For example I get the last value of x-axis as:

```
window.chart.xAxis[0].getExtremes().max
```

How to find the corresponding y-axis value?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to look through the series data points to find the point with the correct x value, and then just read it's y value.

The points can be obtained using

```
chart.series[0].data
```

This returns an array of points. Iterate through the array until you find the point corresponding to your required x value.

Comment: I want to know for that x-value which is not in the data. Suppose i have grade report to be shown in highChart. For 4th July it is 50 and for 5th Sep it is 70. I want to know the value for 5th August.

Comment: As SteveP posted you need to iterate on each data in series and check value.

Comment: I think that what @RatneshLal wants is interpolation of the Y value for a X value not in the data, but between two given data point.

Comment: @Mortimer yes true, exactly i want to know between the two given point.

Comment: @RatneshLal, this is non trivial, first you need to find the two data points around your point in the actual data (dichotomy search I guess). Once that is done, you need to interpolate the value, but to do that you need to know the function that describes your data.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very late to the party, and this method might not have been available at the time.
But if you don't need to interpolate and rather just get the nearest data point to some coordinate, there is the method [`findNearestKDPoint`](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Pointer#findNearestKDPoint) on the [`chart.pointer` property](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#pointer).

It takes the array of series you wish to consider and an event that contains chart coordinates (i.e. has `chartX` and `chartY` properties), and returns the nearest point in the array of series to those coordinates.

[Looking at the documentation in the source code](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/19a093ea3226ef676dd43e4ac91ce3c8dd3086ed/ts/Core/Series/Series.ts#L5958), for 1D series like lines, the search will only consider the x-ordinate of the event. Which is useful in this case.

So we can do something like this:

```js
function nearest_y_from_x(series, x) {
    const x_data_value = series.xAxis.toPixels(x, true);
    return series.chart.pointer.findNearestKDPoint([series], false, {chartX: x_data_value}).y;
}
```

Where `series` is the series object you want to get the value from, and `x` is the x-axis value.